# unable to install magento 2.2.4 on xampp

Tags: magento2, installation

I'm trying to install default Magento 2.2.4 version on xampp.
on step 6 (last step) I'm getting this error:

> [ERROR] LogicException: Unknown module in the requested list: 'Magento_BundleSampleData' in C:\newxampp\htdocs\magento2\Magento-CE-2.2.4-2018-05-01-09-28-45\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php:430 Stack trace: #0 C:\newxampp\htdocs\magento2\Magento-CE-2.2.4-2018-05-01-09-28-45\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(389): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->readListOfModules(Array, Array, 'enable_modules') #1 C:\newxampp\htdocs\magento2\Magento-CE-2.2.4-2018-05-01-09-28-45\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(334): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->createModulesConfig(Array, true) #2 C:\newxampp\htdocs\magento2\Magento-CE-2.2.4-2018-05-01-09-28-45\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #3 C:\newxampp\htdocs\magento2\Magento-CE-2.2.4-2018-05-01-09-28-45\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #4 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #5 C:\newxampp\htdocs\magento2\Magento-CE-2.2.4-2018-05-01-09-28-45\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #6 C:\newxampp\htdocs\magento2\Magento-CE-2.2.4-2018-05-01-09-28-45\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #7 C:\newxampp\htdocs\magento2\Magento-CE-2.2.4-2018-05-01-09-28-45\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #8 C:\newxampp\htdocs\magento2\Magento-CE-2.2.4-2018-05-01-09-28-45\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #9 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #10 C:\newxampp\htdocs\magento2\Magento-CE-2.2.4-2018-05-01-09-28-45\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #11 C:\newxampp\htdocs\magento2\Magento-CE-2.2.4-2018-05-01-09-28-45\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #12 C:\newxampp\htdocs\magento2\Magento-CE-2.2.4-2018-05-01-09-28-45\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #13 C:\newxampp\htdocs\magento2\Magento-CE-2.2.4-2018-05-01-09-28-45\setup\index.php(35): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #14 {main}

also, I have tried to install different Magento 2 theme and it's showing me the same error on the console log.

Comment: From where you have downloaded the Magento 2.2.4 zip?

Comment: @SukumarGorai i downloaded it from magento.com

Comment: Clear the browser cache and try again.

Comment: Try one of this: 1. bin/magento setup:uninstall   (do backup if you have any data in database that you need)  2. Run installer in incognito window 3. Restart server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was only browser cache, just change the browser . If not working then use incognito browser. it's not mandatory but ones restarting MySQL or Apache has fixed.